# How to totally replace existing Language Service with new one

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I developed a Visual Studio Language Service to replace one of existing third party's.
That existing language service accompanied with Project System (developed in native VC++).
And it forces every file open action to use it's own language service.

Scenarios are:

1. File opens through Solution Explorer.
2. File opens through Go To Definition command.
3. File opens through Add New Item dialog.

In all this scenarios third party sets their own Language Service GUID to IVsTextBuffer.
It's seems that they use some kind of OpenFile method post processing techniques.

I need to totally replace their Language Service with my one. How I could do this?
Or how I could get notified of Editor Open file (or Show Editor Window)?

P.S.

In my scenario I implemented custom EditorFactory that instantiate CoreEditor and sets my LanguageService, but then it replaced by third party one.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.
I opened this question at [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec34e38b-b06e-4dd5-83c3-e85b7f128077/how-to-totally-replace-existing-language-service-with-new-one?forum=vsx). I have tried the IVsTextViewCreationListener, but it is not help for me. If you could help, pleace take a look on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec34e38b-b06e-4dd5-83c3-e85b7f128077/how-to-totally-replace-existing-language-service-with-new-one?forum=vsx).

Comment: You can also be notified of files being opened by exporting an IVsTextViewCreationListener via MEF, but I don't know what the default priorities are or if they can be changed. Interesting question!

Comment: I read about suggested IVsTextViewCreationListener and it seems to exist just from VS2010. I need solid solution for VS2005/2008/2010, but thanks for info. I also discovered that documents time to time opens in so called 'invisible mode', when no WindowFrame created. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, afraid not. I'm currently working with VS2013, and have almost no experience with the internals of the older VSes.